# felicegattuso's date picker reset time

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin to set the date on some of my posts - [datedropper](http://felicegattuso.com/projects/datedropper/)

One of the requirements is to have a button that set the date as today. I know how can I get the date but I can't find where this plugin is storing the current date so I can alter it.

Currently, I don't have some relevant code for this question, as I'm stuck in the beggining